# In GCP how can I access any file located locally in my system from GCP Cloud Shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to GCP, I have a Service Account key json file in my system and I want to use this file from Cloud Shell.

1. I tried to search any command through which I can generate Service account key but couldn't able to find.
2. I installed 'gcloud cli' in my local system through which I can use my existing key file, however I need to use it through Cloud Shell.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching I found a very simple solution available right up front.

Actually in Cloud Shell on the right hand corner there is three vertical dots (More), upon clicking it provides multiple options like Upload, Download etc.

[image]

This is also documented officially, from where I got to know this:
https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/uploading-and-downloading-files

One thing to keep in mind though:
This options are not clickable until you are connected to any Project in the Cloud Shell.